# Undefined Method '+' for Nil Class

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have this code:

```
<% @accessories.each do |accessory|%>
    <div>
        <%= image_tag(accessory.firebrick_qcg.url , :"title" => accessory.part_number , :"alt" => accessory.description , :"data-size" => accessory.width.to_s + "," + accessory.height , :"data-size2" => accessory.width2.to_s + "," + accessory.height2 , :"data-img1" => accessory.firebrick_qcg.url , :"data-img2" => accessory.firebrick_qcr.url, :"data-img3" => accessory.firebrick_rg.url , class: "img-responsive") %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
```

Ican't see what is wrong. If someone can help me.

Comment: seems you have passed `nil` into the `image_tag` please validate with `pry` which argument is evaluated to nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an error on concatenating, use `"#{}"` to concatenate in ruby for strings.

Fix spaces and extra lines before save.

```
<% @accessories.each do |accessory|%>
    <div>
        <%= image_tag(accessory.firebrick_qcg.url, 
        :"title" => accessory.part_number, 
        :"alt" => accessory.description, 
        :"data-size" => "#{accessory.width.to_s}, accessory.height",
        :"data-size2" => "#{accessory.width2.to_s}, #{accessory.height2}", 
        :"data-img1" => accessory.firebrick_qcg.url, 
        :"data-img2" => accessory.firebrick_qcr.url, 
        :"data-img3" => accessory.firebrick_rg.url , 
        class: "img-responsive") %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you @7urkm3n